# Get and output full size of image

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to output the full size of images in wordpress. This is my code:

```
    <div class="content project clearfix">
    <?php if( have_rows('galeria') ):
            while ( have_rows('galeria') ) : the_row(); 
                $image = get_sub_field('imagen');
                $image_url = $image['sizes']['full'];?>
                <img class="project-item" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
            <?php  endwhile;
    endif; ?>
    </div>
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in /Users/user/Sites/diana/wp-content/themes/site/single.php on line 13

Warning: Illegal string offset 'full' in /Users/user/Sites/diana/wp-content/themes/site/single.php on line 13
```

I want to ouput the image with the `width` and `height` attributes (these attr are variable, every image has different sizes). Just like this:

```
<img class="project-item" src="img2.jpg" width="422" height="754">
```

Comment: The code you have shared does not appear to be the code that's throwing the error.  I see no reference to `medium` in your code.

Comment: seems like you havnt used `medium` reference in the code

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the error is with `full`. I was just trying to use `medium` size also but the I got the problem. I have updated the question

Comment: Either way, just try to `var_dump()` or `print_r()` the variable before you use it.  Debug.  Your `get_sub_field()` function isn't returning what you think it's returning.

Comment: Ok @Crontab. Can you help me with the actual question please? I see you very interested

Comment: @codek...That was helping. What happens if you `var_dump($image)`?

Comment: @mevius Ok. If I `var_dump($image)` I get the same error plus: `string(59) http://site.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/project-1.jpg`

Comment: That means your `$image` variable is a `string` that holds the source of the image. It's not an `array`, so it has no `sizes`.

Comment: but the `sizes` aren't default from wordpress function?

Comment: `get_sub_field();`, which you're using to get `$image` is not a default WordPress function. It's an [ACF function](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/). It has no `sizes`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64331/discussion-between-codek-and-rnevius).

Comment: If you want to utilize image sizes in ACF, you need to set the field settings to return either the ID or the Image Object.

Comment: But how can I do that? I don't understand, I thought the sizes were default. `full`, `medium`, etc

Comment: Sizes are, for things like [wp_get_attachment_image()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)...but you're not using a WordPress function.

Comment: In advanced custom fields, where you defined your galeria and imagen fields, the imagen field should have a radio button group called "Return Value", with 3 options: Image Array, Image URL, and Image ID. You most likely have that set to Image URL, which returns the URL of the full size image. You cannot call sizes from that value. You would be best to use the Image ID, and then get the URL of various image sizes from that ID using wp_get_attachment_image_src().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joe mentioned, you should modify the ACF image field to get the `ID` instead of the `URL`.

You'll then want to use [wp_get_attachment_img_src()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src). This will return an array containing:

- [0] => url
- [1] => width
- [2] => height
- [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.

So, in your case, the use would be:

```
<div class="content project clearfix">
    <?php if( have_rows('galeria') ):
        while ( have_rows('galeria') ) : 
            the_row(); 
            $image = get_sub_field('imagen');
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, 'full' ); ?>
            <img class="project-item" src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
        <?php  endwhile;
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use [wp_get_attachment_image()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image), which will allow you to use the image size keywords you have been referring to. In this case, usage would be something like:

```
<div class="content project clearfix">
    <?php if( have_rows('galeria') ):
        while ( have_rows('galeria') ) : 
            the_row(); 
            $image = get_sub_field('imagen');
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'full' );
        endwhile;
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I just updated to explain how you can use the attachment size keywords. This second method simplifies things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In Advanced Custom Fields (since you're using get_sub_field(), it means you're using that plugin), change your imagen field to return Image ID in the Return Value.

Then, when calling your image, try this:

```
<div class="content project clearfix">
    <?php if( have_rows('galeria') ):
        while ( have_rows('galeria') ) : the_row(); 
            $image = get_sub_field('imagen');
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, 'full' );
            $featImgURL = $featImgURL[0]; ?>
            <img class="project-item" src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
        <?php  endwhile;
    endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed the `img` to get the `ID` instead of `URL` on ACF configuration. Now I'm not getting errors but this is the output: `<img class="project-item" src="&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;b&gt;Notice&lt;/b&gt;:  Array to string conversion in &lt;b&gt;/Users/user/Sites/diana/wp-content/themes/site/single.php&lt;/b&gt; on line &lt;b&gt;8&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
Array" width="100%" height="100%">`

Comment: I forgot a line in my code. Apologies for that. I've edited my answer to reflect it. I added "$featImgURL = $featImgURL[0];". $featImgURL returns an Array, and the $featImgURL[0] returns the url of the image.